# Finding domain of $f \circ g$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, functional-analysis, functions

I am having a small question, please don't close this before answering, I just want to know whether its a matter of convention or not.

If $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$ and $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$

$ $

Then $f \circ g = x$

$ $

I think domain of $f \circ g $ is $\mathbb{R} - \left\{0\right\}$

$ $

But many ppl I know are having an opinion that domain is $\mathbb{R}$

$ $

Which is true, OR is it just a matter of convention.

Answer (score 7):

It's a matter of convention. Indeed, when you say $f(x) = 1/x$, you've not really specified $f$ (it might, for example, only be defined on the domain $x > 4.7$), but by convention, we treat the domain as "as much of the reals as possible" and infer that it's therefore all of $\mathbb R$.

(Slightly amended) When you say that $f \circ g (x) = x$, you've actually written something wrong, in the sense that the function on the left does not have $x = 0$ in its domain, but the function implied by the expression on the right (namely $x \mapsto x$) does; that makes them not equal as functions. A better description of $f \circ g$ is 
$$
f \circ g (x) =  x  \text{ for  $x \ne 0$}
$$
because $x = 0$ is not in the domain of $g$. Better still, 
$$
f \circ g : \mathbb R - \{0\} \to  \mathbb R - \{0\} : x \mapsto x,
$$
although I have to admit that the choice of codomain here is somewhat arbitrary -- I could have made it $\mathbb R - \{0\} \to  \mathbb R$. There's really almost no consistency about this. Some folks want the codomain to be "as small as possible," others may prefer that it's as easy to specify as possible.

But once again, convention (or at least some algebra teachers) often says "we do algebra to the formulas for $f$ and $g$, and deal with the result." But to be honest, I think that most practicing mathematicians would agree with you that the domain of $f$ does not include zero.

Comment: "When you say $f\circ g(x)=x$, you've actually written something wrong." -- I disagree. If that were true, you might as well say that your definition is wrong, as it claims that $f\circ g(\textrm{elephant})=\textrm{elephant}$, while the elephant is not in the domain of $g$!

Comment: @tomasz: What **is** a matter of convention in this discussion is that the symbol $x$ is restricted to values in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @LeeMosher: sure, I get that, and I don't have much of an issue with the latter notation -- I'm just saying that it's not any better than saying $f\circ g(x)=x$.

Comment: It is so unfortunate that stewart calculus, does not agree with us.

Comment: tomasz is, I think, partly right. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: It's probably being the scope of OP's interest, but if you view functions as morphisms (as opposed to binary relations), "the same functions" with distinct codomains are *distinct functions*. Whether you consider functions as morphisms or relations *is* a matter of convention, or more often of convenience.

Comment: I'm not certain of your definition of morphism (or function); my own favorite definition of function is that a function is a triple, $f = (D, C, R)$, where $R \subset D \times C$ is a subset having two properties (which amount to "f(x) is defined for all x in D" and "f(y) = f(x) implies y = x"). With this definition, even *functions* with distinct codomains are distinct as functions. (One downside of this definition: it doesn't allow for 0-ary functions with constant values, which people who program computers seem to want to have.)

Answer (score 0):

For the classical definition of function composition, if $f,g$ are any functions, then the domain of $f\circ g$ is the domain of $g$, *period* (but see the last two paragraphs).

The issue here highlights the problem with the formulation "find the domain of a function" -- a function's domain is a part of its definition. You can't specify a function without specifying a domain.

The formulas you've written could denote functions ${\bf R}\setminus \{0\}\to {\bf R}\setminus \{0\}$, as they could denote functions ${\bf C}\setminus \{0\}\to{\bf C}\setminus \{0\}$ or ${\bf C}\cup\{\infty\}\to{\bf C}\cup\{\infty\}$ or even $\{1,243\}\to\{1,1/243\}$. This very formulation *is* a convention in mathematical education (and an unfortunate one at that). It could be fixed if the definition said that "the domain of $f$ is the maximal set of real numbers for which the formula is meaningful", or something of the sort.

To digress in a different direction: sometimes we consider families of partial functions and identify functions which differ on small sets. For example, if we consider the field of rational functions ${\bf R}(x)$ with "composition" $*$, then $\frac 1 x * \frac 1 x=x$. But this is *not* literally function composition, but either a formal multiplication or an operation on equivalence classes (in case of meromorphic functions, for example).

==Edit==
As John suggested, if the codomain of $g$ and the domain of $f$ do not agree, it is still possible to define $f\circ g$. In this case, the domain of $f\circ g$ is the preimage of the domain of $f$ by $g$. This extension of the usual definition of composition of functions is a special case of composition of binary relations. In this case, too, however, the domain of $f\circ g$ is contained in the domain of $g$.

Comment: What about $x \mapsto arctan(1/x)$? That's the composition of $arctan$ and $x \mapsto 1/x$, but surely its implied domain is $(-\infty, -2/\pi) \cup ( 2/\pi, \infty)$. I agree with you almost completely: $f \circ g$ should not be written unless the domain of $f$ contains the image of $g$. But since "restriction" of functions isn't usually introduced early enough, we're left with problems like this one...and I think it's reasonable to provide a temporary workaround of sorts (i.e., "the domain of $g$ gets further reduced to make sure that its image under $g$ is entirely in the domain of $f$").

Comment: @John: Well, my answer was meant (mostly) to reflect the state of affairs in general mathematics. But you are right that function composition makes sense even if the domain and codomain don't agree: if we interpret the functions as relations which happen to be function, the usual relation composition formula will give what you suggest. I will fix the answer now to include that information. About how it is best to present such exercises in elementary education, I'm not going to discuss, as I don't really feel competent about that.

Answer (score 0):

One sensible way to resolve this issue is to understand what the equation $f \circ g(x)=x$ does and does not say. It does not say "the function $f \circ g(x)$ is the same as the function $x$". By being careful about domains, what this equation *does* say is that "the function $f \circ g(x)$ is the same as the restriction of the function $x$ to the domain of $f \circ g(x)$", and that domain is the set $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, as stated in other answers.

Comment: I think this is reasonable...but have two objections. (1) $f \circ g (x)$ denotes the value of the function $f \circ g$ at $x$. I'd rather write "The function $x \mapsto f \circ g (x)$..." Why? Look at the Fourier transform $\cal F$ on $L^2(R)$. When you write "The function $\cal F(f)$...", are you referring to $f \mapsto \cal F(f)$, i.e., the Fourier transform itself? Or to the function that results from applying the Fourier transform to $f$? This is pedantic...but I care because students screw it up all the time. (2) Isn't redefining equality a pretty big step to fix sloppy terminology?

Comment: I agree with you on notation. I too care that students learn to write things correctly. In this case I took some liberties to try to make a point to the OP.

Comment: Understood. When I taught calculus, I used to point out, at least once, that the functions $t \mapsto t^2$ and $x \mapsto x^2$ were exactly the same. Students mostly ignored me and continued to talk about "the function $x^2$".

Answer (score 0):

Functions are like input output machines and composite functions are a combination of them. Thus when you consider f(g(x)), the domain cannot be greater than the domain of g(x) because if g(x) cannot process a x value then how can f(g(x))?

It does not do to just simplify composite functions because if f(g(x)) = x then can't we just make another function named h(x) =x but we don't. Why? so that the function f(g(x)) depends on the domain of the functions f(x) and g(x).